# Regexp to match repeated substring

Tags: ruby, regex

I would like to verify a string containing repeated substrings. The substrings have a particular structure. Whole string has a particular structure (substring split by `"|"`). For instance, the string can be:

```
1=23.00|6=22.12|12=21.34|112=20.34
1=23.00|6=22.12|12=21.34
1=23.00|12=21.34
1=23.00**
```

How can I check that all repeated substrings match a regexp? I tried to check it with:

```
"1=23.00|6=22.12|12=21.34".match(/([1-9][0-9]*[=][0-9\.]+)+/)
```

But checking gives `true` even when several substrings do not match the regexp:

```
"1=23.00|6=ass|=21.34".match(/([1-9][0-9]*[=][0-9\.]+)+/)
# => #<MatchData "1=23.00" 1:"1=23.00">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is whether every repeated substring matches a regex.  I understand that the substrings are separated by the character `|` or `$/`, the latter being the end of a line.  We first need to obtain the repeated substrings:

```
a = str.split(/[#{$/}\|]/)
       .map(&:strip)
       .group_by {|s| s}
       .select {|_,v| v.size > 1 }
       .keys
```

Next we specify whatever regex you wish to use.  I am assuming it is this:

```
REGEX = /[1-9][0-9]*=[1-9]+\.[0-9]+/
```

but it could be altered if you have other requirements.

As we wish to determine if all repeated substrings match the regex, that is simply:

```
a.all? {|s| s =~ REGEX}
```

Here are the calculations:

```
str =<<_
1=23.00|6=22.12|12=21.34|112=20.34
1=23.00|6=22.12|12=21.34
1=23.00|12=21.34
1=23.00**
_
c = str.split(/[#{$/}\|]/)
  #=> ["1=23.00", "6=22.12", "12=21.34", "112=20.34", "1=23.00",
  #    "6=22.12", "12=21.34", "1=23.00", "12=21.34", "1=23.00**"] 
d = c.map(&:strip)
  # same as c, possibly not needed or not wanted
e = d.group_by {|s| s}
  # => {"1=23.00"  =>["1=23.00", "1=23.00", "1=23.00"],
  #     "6=22.12"  =>["6=22.12", "6=22.12"],
  #     "12=21.34" =>["12=21.34", "12=21.34", "12=21.34"],
  #     "112=20.34"=>["112=20.34"], "1=23.00**"=>["1=23.00**"]} 
f = e.select {|_,v| v.size > 1 }
  #=> {"1=23.00"=>["1=23.00",  "1=23.00" ,  "1=23.00"],
  #    "6=22.12"=>["6=22.12",  "6=22.12"],
  #   "12=21.34"=>["12=21.34", "12=21.34", "12=21.34"]} 
a = f.keys
  #=> ["1=23.00", "6=22.12", "12=21.34"] 
a.all? {|s| s =~ REGEX}
  #=> true
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return `true` if there are any duplicates, `false` if there are not:

```
s = "1=23.00|6=22.12|12=21.34|112=20.34|3=23.00"
arr = s.split(/\|/).map { |s| s.gsub(/\d=/, "") }

arr != arr.uniq # => true
```

Comment: This returns `true` for `s = "21=23.00|22=23.00"` and for `s = "6='cat'|6='cat'"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve it through regexp (not ruby), you should match whole string, not substrings. Well, I added [|] symbol and line ending to your regexp and it should works like you want.

```
([1-9][0-9]*[=][0-9\.]+[|]*)+$
```

Try it out.